# Merge two expressions of same type (without bool)

Tags: c#, expression, func

I have a method which takes expression `Expression<Func<TFoo, string>> exp`.

I can pass single expression like this

```
MyMethod(o => o.SomeStringProperty);
```

But now i want to combine expressions (from two string properties) and pass in this method

Every other example I found is of `Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>`.

I tried

```
Expression<Func<TFoo, string>> fn1 = x => x.SomeStringProperty1;
Expression<Func<TFoo, string>> fn2 = x => x.SomeStringProperty2;

var body = Expression.Coalesce(fn1.Body, fn2.Body);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TFoo, string>>(body, fn1.Parameters[0]);
```

but almost every function of Expression throws exception. How to do this combine?

Comment: What do you mean by "combine" two expressions? In your example, you are just calling a method with two arguments.

Comment: @IvanStoev: Updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When combining lambda expressions, you should make sure they are bound to the one and the same parameter **instances** used in the resulting expression.

It can be achieved in two ways.

The first is to use [`Expression.Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var body = Expression.Coalesce(fn1.Body, Expression.Invoke(fn2, fn1.Parameters[0]));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TFoo, string>>(body, fn1.Parameters[0]);
```

This is the simplest method, but creates unsupported expression for Entity Framework and similar which do not support invocation expressions.

The second approach uses a simple parameter replacer helper to rebind the second lambda expression body to the first lambda expression parameter:

```
public static class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression, ParameterExpression source, Expression target)
    {
        return new ParameterReplacer { Source = source, Target = target }.Visit(expression);
    }
    class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression Source;
        public Expression Target;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            return node == Source ? Target : base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }
}
```

like this

```
var body = Expression.Coalesce(fn1.Body, 
    fn2.Body.ReplaceParameter(fn2.Parameters[0], fn1.Parameters[0]));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TFoo, string>>(body, fn1.Parameters[0]);
```